# How-to Make a JS Confirm Below leaving the page function

Tags: javascript, jquery, gmail

Google Docs, Gmail etc have this feature where if you try to leave a page that hasn't been saved it pops a dialog box with "confirm, Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?"

Is there a JQUERY plugin that will allow me to implement this kind of functionality?

Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow also does this when you navigate away from an unsaved answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the window.onbeforeunload event, which is not supported in all browser, so don't count on it.

Here's the [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907(VS.85).aspx) for it - it was originally an IE only event.

Answer (score 1):

`window.onbeforeunload;` it does appear that there are efforts to Standardize the event between browsers too: http://kenbrowning.blogspot.com/2009/01/using-jquery-to-standardize.html

Answer (score 0):

I just found this which seems to be an elegant solution too: http://www.jonstjohn.com/node/23